# (C++) Storing an array in a struct

Tags: c++, struct

How can I make a struct that contains an array of values inside it to be accessed?

I have something like:

```
struct stuff {

  int * list;

  stuff {
    list(int[5]) = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  }

}
```

This seems to work alright for storing, but in another file, I am accessing this array:

```
stuff test;
std::cout << test.list[1];
```

And ths is giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: That's not C++ syntax at all. You should post actual code.

Comment: If the array has a fixed length use `std::array` otherwise use `std::vector`.

Comment: Why not just use `std::array<int, 5>`?  Also, it isn't a good idea to use `list` as a variable name, as there is a `std::list` in C++.

Comment: That is not valid syntax at all. I don't see how that "works alright".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Here's how to do it in C++:

```
struct stuff {
    std::vector<int> list;
    stuff() : list({0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) {}
};
```

and then:

```
stuff test;
std::cout << test.list[1];
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83a583d911036a44)

Where `std::vector` is an array-like container that is able (with some trade offs) to store a variable array of elements. If your elements are going to be of fixed size (5 in your case), you can use `std::array` instead, as `std::array<int, 5>`.

The closest working code that you can get from your code is:

```
struct stuff {
    int* list;
    stuff() : list(new int[5] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) {}
};
```

This is, however, a **terrible** idea. It introduces memory leaks and handicapped semantic (`stuff a = stuff()` will lead to shared memory and possibly UB later on). `std::vector` or `std::array`, on the other hand, are as safe as you can get (at least on the memory safety level).

Comment: @user3724236 _'This is exactly what i was looking for!!!'_ Surely?? Read the parts recommending [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) thoroughly again!